# Unable to locate package tlp during tlp installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I just want to reduce the heating in my laptop. So i want to install TLP power management. so i proceed these commands

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw smartmontools ethtool
```

When i am using third command i get the error like this

```
saravanakumar@saravanakumar-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC:~$ sudo apt-get install tlp     tlp-rdw smartmontools ethtool
[sudo] password for saravanakumar: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tlp
E: Unable to locate package tlp-rdw
```

Please anyone help me to install this tlp manager

Comment: I am having the same problem, please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
su
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu lucid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 02D65EFF; apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 02D65EFF
apt-get update
apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

I got it from [here](http://www.techlw.com/2013/07/manage-your-laptop-powerbattery-life-in.html)